# Add data to Room

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I'm creating a vocabulary application. I want to have a feature that when adding a word to a Room, if the added word already exists in the Room, the add button will not allow the user to click on it. I have created a suspend function exitItem( ) in viewModel to check whether the word the user entered exists or not, the function returns true if the word already exists in room . Can anyone help me with the solution? Sincerely thank you.

This is the screen to add words :

[image]

Here is the ViewModel code

```
class ItemEntryViewModel(private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository) : ViewModel() {
    var itemUiState by mutableStateOf(ItemUiState())
        private set

     fun updateUiState(itemDetails: ItemDetails) {
        itemUiState =
            ItemUiState(itemDetails = itemDetails, isEntryValid = validateInput(itemDetails))
    }

    suspend fun exitItem(): Boolean {
        return itemsRepository.isExistItem(word = itemUiState.itemDetails.word)
    }
    suspend fun saveItem() {
        if (validateInput()&&!exitItem()) {
            itemsRepository.insertItem(itemUiState.itemDetails.toItem())
        }
    }

    private  fun validateInput(uiState: ItemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails): Boolean {
        return with(uiState) {
            meaning.isNotBlank() && word.isNotBlank()
        }
    }
}
data class ItemUiState(
    val itemDetails: ItemDetails = ItemDetails(),
    val isEntryValid: Boolean = false,
    val isExit: Boolean = false
)

data class ItemDetails(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val word:String="",
    val meaning: String = ""
)

fun ItemDetails.toItem(): Item = Item(
    id = id,
    word=word,
    meaning = meaning
)

fun Item.toItemUiState(isEntryValid: Boolean = false,isExit: Boolean=false): ItemUiState = ItemUiState(
    itemDetails = this.toItemDetails(),
    isEntryValid = isEntryValid,
    isExit = isExit
)

fun Item.toItemDetails(): ItemDetails = ItemDetails(
    id = id,
    meaning=meaning,
    word = word

)
```

In there:
The updateUiState() function is used to update data in the ViewModel when the user changes from the UI.
The validateInput() function is used to check whether the user has entered the Word and Meaning fields.
The saveItem() function is used to write data to Room.

Here is the UI code

```
@Composable
fun ItemEntryScreen(
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = true,
    viewModel: ItemEntryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            WordTopAppBar(
                title = stringResource(ItemEntryDestination.titleRes),
                canNavigateBack = canNavigateBack,
                navigateUp = onNavigateUp
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        ItemEntryBody(
            itemUiState = viewModel.itemUiState,
            onItemValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            onSaveClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.saveItem()
                    navigateBack()
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemEntryBody(
    itemUiState: ItemUiState,
    onItemValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,

) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large))
    ) {
        ItemInputForm(
            itemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails,
            onValueChange = onItemValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Button(
            onClick = onSaveClick,
            enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.save_action))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemInputForm(
    itemDetails: ItemDetails,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit = {},
    enabled: Boolean = true
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium))
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = itemDetails.word,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(word = it)) },
            label = { Text("WORD") },
            colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            enabled = enabled,
            singleLine = true
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = itemDetails.meaning,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(meaning = it)) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.item_name_req)) },
            colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            enabled = enabled,
            singleLine = true
        )
        if (enabled) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.required_fields),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what error or difficulty you are facing?

Comment: Is there a way to use the result of the exitItem() function in a ViewModel that maps to the UI? Because exitItem() is a suspend, I don't seem to know how to assign it to the button's enabled.

Comment: @HanifShaikh Sorry for my confusing wording, what I mean is that when the user enters a Word, if the Word is already available in the Room then enable of the button = False to prevent the user from clicking the button.  I've got an exitItem() function in the Viewmodel that checks if the Word is already in the Room.  I don't know how to use this result together with itemUiState.isEntryValid

Answer (score 1):

Querying the db on each `TextField` update would be pretty expensive. Instead we could get a `Flow` of list of existing words and check against it. It would be better to get a sorted list and use binary search instead of looking through the whole list every time. So in the repository we would have to add something like:

```
fun getAllWordsOrdered(): Flow<List<String>>
```

In the `ViewModel` we collect that `Flow`:

```
private val words = itemsRepository.getAllWordsOrdered()
    .map { words ->
        words.map { it.lowercase() }
    }
    .stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        initialValue = emptyList<String>()
    )
```

In `validateInput` we look for the word. Note that `binarySearch` expects list to be sorted in ascending order.

```
private fun validateInput(uiState: ItemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails): Boolean {
    return with(uiState) {
        meaning.isNotBlank() && word.isNotBlank() && !wordExist(word)
    }
}

private fun wordExist(word: String): Boolean {
    return words.value.binarySearch(word.lowercase()) >= 0
}
```

Comment: Sir, I followed but my code still doesn't work, it seems like the exitItem() function always returns false.
My code :
private fun exitItem(uiState: ItemDetails): Boolean {
        _wordExists.value = words.value.binarySearch(uiState.word)>=0
        return _wordExists.value
    }

Comment: I edited my answer. In this implementation `exitItem` won't be necessary, we check if word already exists in `validateInput`, so button should become disabled if it does. @TrầnThanhVinh

Comment: Thank you sir, your solution works but there is a problem. For example, in Room there is already the word is book. When I enter book, the Button button is blocked. This is what I want, but when I add a word like 1, that is, the field becomes book1, the button is still blocked. If I continue to add the word 1, the field is book11 then the button allows selection

Comment: Thank you, I have completely revised the code as you provided. The old code you provided violates CONCURRENCY when updating the stateflow again, causing the stateflow to not update properly.

Comment: Good, but there is at least one more thing we should care about - capitalization. I added conversion to lowercase to `wordExist()` and `words StateFlow` creation. @TrầnThanhVinh